# JQuery UI, Combining Sortable with Droppable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to combine JQuery UI **sortable** with **droppable** to create multiple pages for dropping and sorting things. I have setup a blog entry with a stand-along demo here:

http://whit.info/blog/2009/06/06/jquery-ui-combining-sortable-with-droppable/

and here is a jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/VUuyx/

Note that you can drag to sort the boxes, even into other columns. You can also click the page buttons to switch pages. My problem lies in combining these two features:

By using **droppable**, I've allowed the user to drag a box to a *page* button, the page will then switch, and the user can finish dragging it onto the newly revealed page. The problem is that when the page switches, the first column which appears under the dragged box doesn't have it's **over** event fire. You have to drag to another column, and then back to the first column to get the placeholder to appear.

I'm not sure, but I think I need to somehow clear the events, or fire them manually. The problem seems to stem from the fact that the dragged box is over the column when it is made visible.

Can you assist with this esoteric dilemma?

Thanks!

**Update:**

So I have been considering possible work arounds for this. Michal suggested firing the refresh method, which indeed doesn't solve the problem, but made me think about event issues.

It seems that when you mouse away and then back again, the proper events fire. Perhaps if I can manually fire the mouseout event for the first column, the reset will allow the mouseover event to fire properly.

I tried this:

```
$(".column:first").trigger('mouseout');
```

But I don't think that is the same as **sortable**'s out event. Perhaps I should fire *that* event?

Comment: +1 for a pretty decent use of the term "dilemma". Everyone calls his/her problem a "dilemma", even though there are three or four aspects to the problem.

Comment: Nothing worse than a quadrilemma. :)

Comment: Adding `$('.column').sortable('refresh');` to the `.over` callback of the droppable helps, but it is inconsistent. I can't figure out how to get the sortable item to appear at the top of column all the time.

Comment: FYI, this doesnt work at all in IE7

Comment: +1 for the question but also for introducing me to [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/). This is a nice sandbox to try new features and discuss them with others, or showing your code and result when asking for help.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding the problem, but I don't think it has anything to do with the "page switching". If you turn on both pages at the same time and try to drag "Box 1" to a position above "Box 4", you'll see that it doesn't trigger that "Box 4"'s Sortable has received the Draggable until you go *below* "Box 4". This doesn't solve your problem, but perhaps will help you look in a better area for the solution.

See http://jsfiddle.net/nkBNP/7/ for a JSFiddle that demonstrates what I mean.

Comment: You're right. I doesn't seem to be about the page switching at all.

Comment: The issue appears to be that you cannot drop from the top down (or that from the top down it will not go to the spot above the highest item).

Answer (score 1):

At least for the top down drop in I think the solution is somewhere in setting the box class to **draggable** and link it to the sortable object.

```
$(".box").draggable({
    tolerance: 'point',
    connectToSortable: '.column',
    snap:false,
    helper : 'clone',
});
```

This example creates a duplicate of the box but it does allow me to drag box 1 up to page 2 and slowly drag it down above box 5 and get placed into the top spot. It is very sensitive though. You may need to adjust the grids and snap to get it to work consistently for the casual user.

I can certainly imagine that a sortable object wouldn't expect something to come down from the top, because it expects things to be sorted from within the container. Droppable on the other hand expects things to enter from any direction.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah adding $('.column').sortable("refresh");
to end of the show_page(id) function worked for me (only tested in firefox minefield):

```
function show_page(id) {
    $('.page').removeClass('page_active');
    $('#page_'+id).addClass('page_active');
    $('.column').sortable("refresh");
}
```

Comment: Not for me. Both Firefox and Chrome have the same behavior for me (even with the refresh): When the page switches, the box cannot be placed in the first position of the first column. The placeholder doesn't show up. Sometimes it appears for the second position, but to get it into first postion you must mouse away and then back again. Here's a screenshot: http://bit.ly/dmxl6T

Comment: sorry it didn't work, i just tested in chrome, too, and the fix worked for me there as well.  Maybe it's different on different platforms or versions (I'm in ubuntu using the nightly versions of chrome and firefox).

Answer (score 0):

Adding @edtechdev's answer to `tolerance: 'intersect` produced something I thought might satisfy you, Whit:

```
$(".column").sortable({
    connectWith: '.column',
    opacity: 0.4,
    tolerance: 'intersect', //<--changed
    placeholder: 'place_holder',
    helper: function(event, el) {
        var myclone = el.clone();
        $('body').append(myclone);
        return myclone;
    },
}).disableSelection();

// ...

function show_page(id) {
    $('.page').removeClass('page_active');
    $('#page_'+id).addClass('page_active');
    $('#page_'+id).find('.column:first').sortable('refresh'); //<- added
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out drag and drop portal built using jQuery and Asp.Net MVC, it has all implementation in blog posts: http://lakkakula.wordpress.com/2009/06/15/web-2-0-portal-using-asp-net-mvc-microsoft-ajax-client-templates-and-jquery-with-drag-and-drop-widget-personalization/

Answer (score 0):

Sortable has an undocumented option `refreshPositions` which automatically updates the position of your droppables when they are sortable as well. This prevents the placeholder from being droppable instead of the actual droppable.

Comment: Do you have an example of how to use refreshPositions?